# Initializing termios structure to work as VT100

Tags: c, linux, terminal, termios

I'm trying to write program similar to shell, but combined with terminal emulator. The reason do that is I cannot flush write buffer to send data to program or program checks input/output is a pipe.

The problem is with setting termios structure. I would like my pseudoterminal works as standard Linux terminal and it should work with poll, write and read.

I'm using openpty function and login_tty. I'm using openpty twice to open standard input/output terminal and stderr terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds as if you are trying to set terminal modes on a pipe -- which will not work, since the pipe is not a tty.

Comment: I won't use pipe. I would like use pty, but I must set flag to terminal, so It would works as standard Linux terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This code should works.

```
    if (openpty(&fds[0], &fds[1], NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {

      perror("openpty error ");
      return;
    }

    tcgetattr(fds[0], &termios);
    termios.c_lflag &= OUR_FLAGS;
    tcsetattr(fds[0], TCSANOW, &termios);
```

The problem was I don't know, which flags are setting by openpty, but it looks like it configures terminal correctly.

I setting control flags only for example. In my case I have disabled echo like this

```
    termios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
```